Why do higher objects have a greater force?
We did an experiment in class today using a spring scale, a plastic bag, and a variety of other objects. Essentially, we attached the bag to the spring scale and measured the force, in newtons, of different objects/combinations of objects by placing them in the bag. Simple enough. Then, however, our teacher told us that the higher the spring scale was held, making the objects higher up as well, the greater the force would be when measured on the scale. As we had always been taught that gravitational force weakened with distance, and more height means more distance, I was confused as to how this was possible. Does it have anything to do with gravitational potential energy? If not, what does it have to do with? Thanks!

What do you mean by "higher objects"? Were you dropping these objects from a height into the bag?

I ditto Filip's question

maybe just a communication barrier, Ask him next time exactly what he meant by Higher objects. If Higher object means higher object mass, Then yes, For same height, Heavier object has greater force of gravitation By earth compared to lighter object

I meant that when the spring scale was raised higher off the ground, the objects in the plastic bag measured more in newtons, or force. Sorry that wasn't more clear before.

@user386598 To stand a chance of getting your question reopened, you should edit your question and add the clarification to it.

I tried editing it but I'm sort of confused about the topic in general and I don't know how much better I can do.

Voting to reopen. The question is perfectly clear.

It sounds wrong to me, or maybe something was lost in communication and that's not what he said or meant.
You're right about gravitational force weakening with distance (inverse square law), but for practical purposes, near the surface of the Earth, the acceleration due to gravity is constant at about $9.8m/s^2$

The Force between two objects is defined as:
$$F= \frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$$
Where $G$ is the gravitational constant, $r$ is the distance between the objects, and $m_1$ and $m_2$ are their respective masses. So you can see that force is inversely proportional to the distance between their object, i.e. objects further apart exert less force on each other.
However, for an object as massive as Earth. The effects of this are only relevant at very large $r$, 100km+.
For practical purposes (at and around the surface of the Earth), the Force exerted on an object due to gravity is:
$$F = mg$$
Where $g$ is gravitational acceleration (9.8m/s).
So what your teacher said is correct. Because objects further apart do exert less force on one another, however there is absolutely no way they were able to detect deviations in the weight of objects that were higher up, in a classroom setting. So I suspect there has been an error in communication somewhere.

Slightly off topic, but maybe of interest, it is surprisingly easy to measure the change in air pressure with change in height of a couple of metres, using a u tube manometer open at one end and attached to a rigid air filled bottle at the other.

Thanks, I didn't know, yes that is definitely interesting!
